# My system files take 4,46Gb, is it normal?

Tags: 8.0, storage, games

It took less space yesterday (around 3Gb) And now 4,46...

I remember trying to download a Game yesterday and the download failed at 75% cause I didn't have enough space. Maybe all the files I downloaded so far are redirected to system files?

How do I delete those files?

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing this number?

Comment: Settings > phone storage > phone

Comment: Post a screenshot?

Comment: Here you go karancan

Comment: Are you running Windows Phone 8.1 ?

Comment: No... I use 8.0

Comment: I checked a few different Lumias - some running 8.0 and some running 8.1 and just over 2GB is the norm :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I searched stuff in my phone and I found the "**storage check**" in the settings. It showed that I had 2GB of system BUT apparently what was taking so much space were the temporary files! If you go to **details** you can see Temporary files and you just have to tap on **clear** [image]

Answer (score 1):

That *seems* unusually high - on a Nokia Lumia 1020 running 8.0.10517.150, "system" is only using 2.41 GB for me. Installing other language packs *could* increase that figure, but I wouldn't expect that figure to almost double.

Answer (score 1):

That is unusually high.  Running 8.1 on my 1320 and I Am on 2.61gb. Almost same figure I had when I was running 8.0.
I would recommend to do a backup of personal files and go for a **hard reset** or using **Nokia Care suite to reflash your entire system**
[image]